# Custom your ImageCardView style ( not the content )

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, cardview

How can I custom the `ImageCardView` to be circular in `Leanback`?

Comment: Do you mean circular? So instead of a square the ImageCardView would be a circle?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few ways you could do this. I think the cleaner approach would be creating your own custom `CardView` which extends `BaseCardView`. Then you could create your own [`CardPresenter`](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/presenter/CardPresenter.java) which is capable of presenting that circular card type.

The [leanback showcase](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase) sample app goes into great detail about customizing cards. I'd suggest looking at all of it but the relevant part would be their custom [`CharacterCardView`](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/cards/CharacterCardView.java). Which has it's entirely own [custom layout](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/character_card.xml). And then it has it's own [`CharacterCardPresenter`](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/cards/presenters/CharacterCardPresenter.java). I'd copy the code right into here but those classes links will do much better justice.

The alternative is to override `lb_image_card_view.xml` and replace it with your own circular view. As long as you keep the resource `ids` and the view types the same, you could maybe get away with styling it how you like. `ImageCardView` is also highly styleable which you can read about in the [ImageCardView docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ImageCardView.html).

Comment: Thank you very much ! that is what I am looking for.